# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your app bundle is signed with the correct signing key error

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-apps-script, app-store, google-play-services

I push my app first release the google play console through me error on uploading time, I don't why I'm getting this error, I try to r&d but no successful result please help me to push the app on play store[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZJA0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the project and rebuild it, Android Studio caches the previous location of the app Key and creates issues, it is a major bug and it happened with me too

OR

Assuming this is the first time you are uploading the app, and not posting an update

Delete the app release draft completely and start over again